# (Python) How do I fix the problem "missing 1 required positional arguement: 'self'"?

Tags: python

I am a beginner to python and I am trying to create a discord bot. I was told to add "self" in on_message() arguements but it brought along the new problem of "missing 1 required positional arguement: 'self'".

```
   @client.event
  async def on_message(message, self):
    print(message)
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('-roll'):
      n = random.random()
      await message.channel.send('I rolled' , (n))
```

Comment: ```def on_message(self,message):```

Comment: `self` should be the first argument, and presumably that error is related to where the method is called, which is not in your question.

Comment: @Sujay That won't solve the problem; naming isn't important (at this stage). It would err as *missing argument "message"* if you swap the names. It has something to do with how it is called as khelwood mentioned.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thats the current issue, how can i call self to make it work?

Comment: @Vector Is this under a `class` definition? How is this function somehow called? You need to share enough code for others to help you, i.e., a [mcve]. Maybe you don't need `self` at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Put self as the first argument and message as the second argument.**

```
@client.event    

async def on_message(self,message): #change made here !

    print(message)

    if message.author == client.user:

      return

    if message.content.startswith('-roll'):

      n = random.random()
      await message.channel.send('I rolled' , (n))
```

Comment: When I do that it makes message italicized but self is not, does that mean something? Is it because i don't call anything with self?

Comment: It depends on the code editor formatting  ,  maybe it is telling that "message" here is a variable ,  whereas self is not !

Answer (score 0):

In Python Object Oriented Programming

"self" keyword is required at first parameter

so it should be look like this

```
def on_message(self, message):
```

check this article
https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/